# How can I get rid of this extra whitespace?

Tags: css

On the home page of a site I'm working on, I have a bunch of extra whitespace on the right of the page. I know the problem is in my css, but I'm not sure how to remedy the problem. Here is the relevant css:

```
/* Home Page */

#homelogo {
margin-left: -450px;
margin-right: 0px;
color: #363636;
}

#bigtext {
font-size: 45px;
margin-right: -360px;
position: relative;
bottom: 80px;
line-height: 1;
color: #FF809D;
}

#description {
position: relative;
bottom: 60px;
}
```

Any help you can give me would be great!

Comment: can you show give us the html too please.

Comment: You posted only CSS, so we can't see any whitespace. Set up a JS Fiddle so we can actually see the problem.

Comment: We need some `html` too. Just css cannot tell us what could help.

Comment: Yes, I will set up a JS Fiddle right now. I apologize for not including everything.

Comment: Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LMqF3/1/. I had to take out some embedded ruby, and that is why the upper left corner looks so bare. Thanks for your interest in helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #bigtext {
      font-size: 45px;
      **margin-right: -360px;**
      position: relative;
      bottom: 80px;
      line-height: 1;
      color: #FF809D;
    }
```

the problem is that you are creating extra space to the right with a negative right margin
i.e. it is adding space to the right of the body